# How can I adapt the 2d joystic value to a 3d direction for the character?

Tags: unity, c#

Hello I am trying to move the character in joystick direction

[image]

Green arrow is what I am trying to get.

```
private void OnMovement(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
    {
        if(obj.performed){
            _MovementPoint = new Vector3(-obj.ReadValue<Vector2>().y, 0,obj.ReadValue<Vector2>().x ).normalized;  
            Debug.Log(this.transform.position);
        }
    }
```

And I am calling this on Update

```
 private void Update()
    {
        this.transform.position = this.transform.position + _MovementPoint*Time.deltaTime*6;
    }
```

Is there a way?

Comment: It's problem is it should rotation 45 angle ?

Comment: because your camera is 45 angle

Comment: @TimChang Yes that's what I am trying to do

Comment: @TimChang that worked thanks : newMovementDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(45, Vector3.up) * _MovementPoint;

Answer (score 2):

The screen coordinate system and the world coordinate system are different. You can convert the coordinates by [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html). Find the transformed vector by transforming two points:

```
void Update()
{
    var p1 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector3.zero);
    var p2 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(_MovementPoint);
    var moveDir = p2 - p1;
    this.transform.position += moveDir * Time.deltaTime * 6;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand but this giving me a strange movement.

Comment: @AltC Hello, I found that _MovementPoint is on the x-z screen. Shouldn't it be on the x-y screen?

Comment: Hi, y is upward axis? so that's okay right

Comment: This worked for me : newMovementDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(45, Vector3.up) * _MovementPoint;

Comment: @AltC If you found a solution to your problem that differs from those give, I encourage you to write it up & post it as an answer.